# Grant Create Sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequence, sql-grant

Is it possible to grant a user/role only the permission to create/alter sequences in a PostgreSQL database/schema not allowing the user to create tables at the same time?

I currently use

GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema TO "MyRole";

which gives the user full create access to the schema, though he cannot delete or alter any tables that he does not own. My use case is that I use Liquibase to setup the database schema upfront and want to have the application only using a db user that can only read/write data. Unfortunately the application requires a dynamic number of sequences, i.e. it must be possible for the application to create new sequences in the database/schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way is to create an event trigger that throws an error if you create anything else than a sequence.

Comment: There is an [answer in db stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308616/create-sequence-permission-for-postgres/324872#324872) with an example

Answer (score -2):

You can do

```
grant select on sequence my_sequence in schema my_schema to my_role_user
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-grant.html